# implementation of a C++ function of a class that uses other classes

Tags: c++, oop

```
typedef Map<int, char> StudentMap;

class SchoolManagementSystem
{
private:
    SmarterArray<Student> studentList; //A SmarterArray to store the students in the school
    SmarterArray<Course> courseList; //A SmarterArray to store the courses in the school
    SmarterArray<StudentMap> studentMapList; //A SmarterArray to store the students' maps

public:
    //Constructors
    SchoolManagementSystem();

    //Getters
    int getNumberOfRegisteredStudents() const;
    int getNumberOfCoursesOffered() const;
    int findStudent(const string &firstName, const string &lastName) const;
    Student getStudent(const int &studentIndex) const;
    StudentMap getStudentMap(const int &studentIndex) const;
    int findCourse(const string &courseName) const;
    Course getCourse(const int &courseIndex) const;
    double getStudentGPA(const int &studentIndex) const;
    int getTopStudentIndex() const;

    //Setters
    bool registerStudent(const Student &s);
    bool enrolStudent(const int &studentIndex, const int &courseIndex);
    bool assignLetterGrade(const int &studentIndex, const int &courseIndex, const char &letterGrade);
    bool offerCourse(const Course &course);
    void removeStudent(const int &studentIndex);
    bool withdrawStudent(const int &studentIndex, const int &courseIndex);
    void removeCourse(const int &courseIndex);

    //Static functions
    static Student generateRandomStudent();
    static char generateRandomLetterGrade();

    //Friend functions
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &, const SchoolManagementSystem &);
};



    bool SchoolManagementSystem :: enrolStudent(const int &studentIndex, const int &courseIndex)
{
    assert((studentIndex < this->studentList.getSize() || studentIndex >= 0) && (courseIndex < this->courseList.getSize() || courseIndex >= 0));

    if(this->getStudentMap(studentIndex).findKey(courseIndex) != -1)
        return false;
    else
    {
//        StudentMap S;
//        S.append(courseIndex, 'N');
//
//        this->studentMapList.append(S);

        this->getStudentMap(studentIndex).append(courseIndex, 'N');
        //this->studentMapList[studentIndex].append(courseIndex, 'N');
//        this->getStudentMap(studentIndex).A1.append(courseIndex);
//        this->getStudentMap(studentIndex).A2.

        return true;
    }
}
```

The function definition given below is supposed to add an element in the map class array within the studentMapList array in The SchoolMaganementSystem class. The definition of the function does not do it, I assure you that the appent in SmarterArray, StudentMap works fine when tested individually.

Comment: `getStudentMap` returns a copy of the map. You then insert an element into that temporary copy and then the temporary is gone.

Comment: instead of granting direct access to the private member you should implement the methods needed. Eg there should be a `SchoolManagementSystem::AddStudent` that adds a student to the map.

Answer (score 1):

All of your `get*` methods are returning by value, not by reference, so you get a personal copy that is unrelated to the version stored in the `SchoolManagementSystem` instance. You can change them, but since they're not related to the copy held in the `SchoolManagementSystem` instance, those changes aren't seen anywhere else.

If you need to be able to view the values and mutate them, you should change your current interface of:

```
StudentMap getStudentMap(const int &studentIndex) const;
```

to a paired interface of:

```
StudentMap& getStudentMap(int studentIndex);
const StudentMap& getStudentMap(int studentIndex) const;
```

one of which can be used to get a mutable reference to the `StudentMap` on mutable `SchoolManagementSystem` instances, the other of which provides you an immutable view of the `StudentMap` on constant `SchoolManagementSystem` instances.

Side-note: There is *zero* benefit to accepting `int`s as `const` references (in practice, it usually means passing a 32-64 bit pointer that must be dereferenced to memory rather than just passing the raw [typically] 32 bit `int` itself); just take them by value (I changed the prototypes to behave that way).

All that said, [**463035818_is_not_a_number** is correct when they say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71788168/implementation-of-a-c-function-of-a-class-that-uses-other-classes/71788269#comment126862830_71788168) that the non-constant version of the method is kind of a misuse of accessors; hiding the implementation but then effectively providing full access to it through an accessor (that allows users to violate whatever design constraints it is supposed to be under) gains very little. As they suggest, provide APIs on the class that allow for specific, allowed mutations (with input checks, constraint validation, what have you) instead of leaving it to users to write functions that mutate it from the outside in arbitrary ways.

Comment: another side-note: There is zero benefit of declaring a member private and returning a non-const reference. Once the caller has a non-const reference encapsulation is broken and the member can be public as well

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Yeah, I saw your comment above and immediately set about adding that to the end of the answer. There is technically a *small* benefit IIRC (dealing with producing shared libraries that can be redesigned internally without requiring the users to rebuild their projects; as long as the compilers involved don't change ABI, the shared library can change implementation, e.g. validating inputs better or the like, without changing the prototype and existing code should still work), but I'm not 100% confident that applies (and it's a small benefit at best).

Comment: not sure if I understand what you say. Have to think about it when I am less tired I guess ;). The thing is that it would be strange if there was a difference between `foo.get().do_something(); foo.get().do_something_else();` and `auto& x = foo.get(); x.something(); x.do_something_else();` hence if `get` returns a reference it actually cannot do much more than that.

Comment: Yeah, the only "more than that" it could do would be in whatever preprocessing goes into validating and possibly transforming the arguments before retrieving the item to provide a reference to. Usually only meaningful in bug fix cases (oops, the IDs reserve index 0 for some special internal usage and the user isn't allowed to see it, put in a check that raises an exception when `studentIndex` is `0`, rebuild the library and replace it, and with luck, existing programs that weren't violating the rules continue to work since the prototype is unchanged and new programs *can't* violate the rules).